# @OneToMany has an error: mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, polymorphism

My model consists of different types of Budgets. These Budgets have different Attributes.
I want to make a OneToMany Relationship between these different types of Budgets.
So lets say I have BudgetLevel1 that has many BudgetLevel2, which again has many BudgetLevel3.
All these BudgetLevels extend the Class Budget

My Budget Class

```
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
public class Budget {

@Id
private Long id;
private String name;
private BudgetTyp budgetTyp;
private Double amount;
```

BudgetLevel1 Class

```
@Entity(name= "BudgetLevel1 ")
public class BudgetLevel1 extends Budget {

@OneToMany(
            **mappedBy="attBudgetLevel2 ",**
            cascade=CascadeType.ALL,
            orphanRemoval=true
            )
private List<BudgetLevel2> budgets= new ArrayList<>();
private String att1;
```

BudgetLevel2 Class

```
@Entity(name= "BudgetLevel2")
public class BudgetLevel2 extends Budget {

@OneToMany(
            mappedBy="budgetlevel2",
            cascade=CascadeType.ALL,
            orphanRemoval=true
            )
private List<BudgetLevel3> budgets= new ArrayList<>();

**@ManyToOne( fetch=FetchType.LAZY,
        cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST)
@JoinColumn(name="budget_id")
Private BudgetLevel2 attBudgetLevel2;**

private String att2;
```

Budgetlevel3 would look similar

this is the error I get

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property: com.bm.ent.geschaeftsfeld.marke.BudgetLevel2.budgetlevel1 in com.bm.ent.geschaeftsfeld.BudegetLevel1.budgetlevel2
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1786) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
>
> org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.5.4.jar:2.5.4]
> Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property: com.bm.ent.geschaeftsfeld.marke.BudgetLevel2.budgetlevel1 in com.bm.ent.geschaeftsfeld.BudegetLevel1.budgetlevel2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mappedBy` works by referencing the actual field names. As you write `mappedBy="budgetlevel2"`, you tell hibernate to look for a field named `budgetlevel2`, which you don't have.

You need to reference the field name directly and to make sure that you have hibernate look in the right entity, also specify the `targetEntity` like this:

```
@OneToMany(
            mappedBy="budgets",
            cascade=CascadeType.ALL,
            orphanRemoval=true,
            targetEntity = BudgetLevel2.class
            )
```

Comment: Your code should be on my BudgetLevel1 right? and the mappedBy = "budgets", budgets is the field name in BudgetLevel2?

Comment: This code is on `BudgetLevel1`, as you have `List<BudgetLevel2>` there. For `BudgetLevel2`, you need to change the `targetEntity` to `BudgetLevel3.class`

Comment: now i get this error Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Illegal use of mappedBy on both sides of the relationship

Comment: This means that your mapping in the question is incomplete. You would need to update the code in your question. And fix all the mistakes you made. You have `public class BudgetLevel1 extends Budget` two times